# Earphone wiring and how do I unscrew the housing from a 3.5mm plug?

Tags: headphones

The 3.5mm plug on my earphones broke. My earphone is the Xiaomi hybrid pro HD. It has the left and right earbud, a 3-button controller and a mic. It has 5 wires:

```
-copper twisted around a white-colored wire (this white-colored wire also has straight copper strands inside it)
-red
-green
-blue
-red twisted with copper.
```

[image: headphone wires]

I'm wondering what these color codes could possibly stand for.

I'm also planning on transplanting my old headphone's 3.5mm plug to this, but I'm wondering how to "unscrew" the housing of this headphone plug[image: headphone plug] to expose the wiring and terminals. Is it possible at all to disassemble the plug's assembly or is it a fixed and sealed unit?

Comment: We can't really tell how it assembles from just the picture. Those plugs come in many styles. Some are screw in, some are snap in, and there's probably others. I would normally say that if it's from a commercial product it is probably not screw-in, but yours looks all-metal which increases your chances. It just might be threadlocked into place or something. Only you can tell since you can look really closely at it.

Comment: It is indeed from a commercial product, the Xiaomi pistons 2 to be exact. Oh well, replacement jacks are cheap so I guess I'll just buy one.

Comment: Be careful of headphone wires. Some of them don't use normal insulation but use a thin transparent coating so it just looks like a bunch of uncoated wire inside but they are actually coated and it can't be stripped off with something like wire cutters. It wasn't clear from your description what kind of wires you have. Don't bother with colour codes. Just measure the resistance between each of the headphone rings and the other end of the wire to figure out what goes where.

Comment: Thanks. I've added a new photo to the main post showing the wiring itself, and it does look like the colors are actually coatings. Never thought repairing headphones would be quite difficult.

Comment: I don't know what that kind of coating is or how to get it off. For magnet wire you can heat up an aspirin under a soldering iron (and don't breathe in the fumes).